# How to insert a paragraph before the chapter title?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I need to include several lines before the chapter title for some (not all) chapters. A new chapter always starts with a new page, how to realize the following layout for certain chapter while other chapters are normal?

```
                              header
-------------------------------------------------------------------
paragraph before the chapter title


Chapter 1 Introduction

   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

-------------------------------------------------------------------
                              footer
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), since chapter styling heavily depends on the document class and other packages you may be using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can temporarily switch off the impact of a `\clearpage` - typically inserted when using `\chapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]

{
\cleardoublepage% Move to first page of new chapter
\let\clearpage\relax% Don't allow page break
\noindent\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Another chapter}
}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Final chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The above example would work in `twoside` mode as well.

Comment: Thanks Werner, I should mention that I'm using `\documentclass{book}`, your code above does not work well for book class.

Comment: I got it, just letting `cleardoublepage` relax works fine, thank you Werner.

Comment: @TonyDong: No; issue `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\clearpage`. I'll update the answer.