# Quote, paragraph, epigraph or doi before the chapter title in memoir class

Tags: memoir, chapters, doi, epigraphs, quotchap

I need to add some text (doi-url link) before the \chapter name.

Unfortunately, two approaches listed below have limitations:

- `\epigraph` is the inlined memoir command to make epigraphs. However `\epigraph` writes the text in the header. This is forbidden. It seems that `geometry` or other packages can help to fix the layout. But the approach looks ugly.
- `quotchap` package fits my need in general. However it redefines all my complex settings of the chapter tittle layout (intervals before and after the title, font, shape etc). It even redefines the settings of memoir class with the following error: `Command \chapnumfont already defined`.

Any ideas or decisions how to add (insert) `\normalfont` text with preset intervals (e.g. `\OnehalfSpacing*`), i.e. before the given in the class settings hspace?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,oneside,openany]{memoir}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{showframe} %to see layout
    \usepackage{url} 
    \usepackage{quotchap} %first variant, which unfortunatelly redefines settings

    \begin{document}

    %Unfortunatelly there is a conflict with memoir class & undesirable modification of the title layout
    \begin{savequote}
        \normalfont`\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.18720/SPBPU/X/XXX-XX}
    \end{savequote}
    \chapter{My chapter title}
    % inlined memoir command
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{\linewidth} %with linewidth
    \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt} %without hline
    \epigraphhead[10]{\epigraph{\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.18720/SPBPU/X/XXX-XX}}{}}
    \end{document}
```

PDF
[image]

Comment: You could just use tikz to place it globally on the chapter page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\dropchapter{1in}% lower chapter title, etc
\chapter{First}
\epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{\textit{To John Doe}}{\textit{2015}}}
\chapter{First}
\undodrop
Text
\end{document}
```

You can use the optional argument (in this case `[70]` to the `\epigraphhead` macro to adjust the vertical position of the epigraph. (see the Epigraphs section in the manual.)

Comment: thank you for the answer. The disadvantage of the decision, that I need to set manually numbers in `\dropchapter{1in}` and `\epigraphhead[70]`. As an alternative there is also a little bit complicated decision here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198886/44348